# Proof of rational + algebraic is algebraic and rational + transcendental is transcendental?

Tags: polynomials, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I've heard of and seen some proofs that the product and sum of two algebraic numbers is algebraic, however many of them are quite complex and require a variety of machinery (from matrix eigenvalues to complex analysis).

Are there simpler proofs of the following?

**A rational + an algebraic is algebraic.**

**A rational + a transcendental is transcendental.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Rational + algebraic = algebraic

Let $x$ be an algebraic number, so $x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n = 0$ for rational numbers $a_1, \cdots, a_n$.

Then, $x+\frac pq$ satisfies the polynomial equation $\left(z-\frac pq\right)^n + a_1 \left(z-\frac pq\right)^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n\left(z-\frac pq\right) = 0$, so it is algebraic.

### Rational + transcendental = transcendental

Let $x$ be transcendental.

If $x+\frac p q$ is algebraic, then so is $\left(x+\frac pq\right) - \frac p q = x$, contradiction. So we conclude that $x+\frac p q$ is transcendental.